# Buzzing and static sound in headphones only when plugged into my pc headphones work fine with everything else

Tags: headphones

There had always been a slight static noise but i learnt to ignore it but now when i plug any headphones in the left ear makes a loud buzzing noise and very little audio goes through that ear, This is a big problem and i play games where it is necessary to be able to head noise. When ever i search this up i get the same results about my drives or the headphone jack. ive done everything updated my drivers deleted them and reinstalled them, cleaned my headphone jack nothing seems to work if anyone could help me fix this i would be very thankful